# AC adapter splitter

Tags: power-supply, cables, split

I'd like to power 2 or more devices (all requiring the same voltage) with a single AC adapter, instead of using multiple adapters.

Is it safe to use one of [these splitter cables](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-12V-Power-Splitter-Cable-Power-Line-for-Surveillance-Cameras-LED-Light-Bar-/131414150593)?

In my case, i have:

- 1 universal DC adapter set as 5VDC and rated 3A max;
- 1 device rated 5VDC 2A
- 1 device rated 5VDC 0.1A

Polarity is the same in both devices.

Is there any risk using these splitter cables?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that each device has it's own protection/fuse it should be safe.

If they do not have protection, in the event of the failure of one, the other could receive an unpredictable power input. Fortunately, even in the worst case, you are only dealing with 15 W of power.

Comment: reportedly the AC adapter (Goobay NTS 3000 MW) has short-circuit protection. Will it still work when using the splitter?

Comment: That's good that it has that protection. Yes it will work. Protection is only if something wrong happens. During normal running, the AC adapter won't be able to tell the difference between two devices or one.